# Matching cell and returning average of multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a Google Sheets with the following sheets:

Heroes

```
A               | B        | C        | D        | E
-------------------------------------------------------
The Flash       | 5        | 10       | 4        | 82
Jesse Quick     | 0        | 2        | 5        | 4
Quicksilver     | 1        | 3        | 12       | 2
Kid Flash       | 10       | 9        | 7        | 17
```

Calc

```
A               | B
-------------------------------------------------------
The Flash       |
Quicksilver     |
```

I want to match **column A** in `Calc` and return the average value of **column B to E** from `Heroes`.

So based on the date above, I want `Calc` should look like this:

```
A               | B
-------------------------------------------------------
The Flash       | 25,25
Quicksilver     | 4,5
```

I had this function in `Calc`:

`=AVERAGEIF(Heroes!A:A;B2;Heroes!B:B))`

changed to:

`=AVERAGEIF(Heroes!A:A;B2;Heroes!B:E))`

but this only returns `5` for *The Flash* and `1` for *Quicksilver*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
    =AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA( VLOOKUP(A5,A12:E13,{2,3,4,5},FALSE)))
```

Where A12:A13 refers to HEROES
and A5 refers to Cal

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AEbci4BN8SyYcmpfOELGRQC4wpRqPn-dUoZy5GdkTyM/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Solved perfectly - `=AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2;Heroes!A:E;{2;3;4;5};FALSE)))`

Answer (score 0):

For the Flash have: `=AVERAGE(Heroes!B1:E1)`

For Quicksilver have: `=AVERAGE(Heroes!B2:E2)`

Using this pattern allows you to get the average of all the Cells in the column of the hero you want. Remember you have to specify the cells, right now you are specifying the whole columns of B-E, when you just want the row of each hero.

Comment: The rows in `Heroes` might get sorted in a different order, so I need to be able to match the cells - can't specify a row number.